# The OS X upgrade couldn't be started because the disk is damaged and can't be repaired

Tags: macbook-pro, software-update, install

My relative was attempting to upgrade her Macbook Pro and it failed. Everytime the laptop boots up, it brings up OS X Installer. The Installer never completes installation because it says the disk is damaged and cannot be repaired.

I cannot boot into recovery mode. Probably because there isn't a recovery partition? When I hold down `option` on startup, the only disk that shows is OS X Installer.

I am Windows/Linux user and not very familiar with Apple computers. What do I do to recover the data and revert everything back to normal?

[image: The OS X upgrade couldn't be started because the disk Macintosh HD is damaged and can't be repaired. After your computer restarts, back up your data, erase your disk, and try installing again.]

Comment: did you try to boot in Safe mode ?

Comment: If you have a hardware disk failure then you can't revert etc without replacing or booting off another disk

Comment: I'm not sure the hard drive has failed. It was working fine before this update.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the MacBookPro after failed Mavericks install (HD damaged and can’t be repaired).   I decided to post this because I spent a day exploring several options in the knowledge base and I had to develop my own procedure to fix the problem.
Summary of the problem:

- Attempting to install Mavericks from OSX 10.6.8 on a MacbookPro
  resulted in the following message: “The OS X upgrade couldn’t be
  started because the disk Macintosh HD is damaged and can’t be
  repaired…”
- Restarting computer only causes OS X installer to run again with the
  same message
- No backup available and restore partition not available
  for OS X 10.6.8
- Disk utility from the OS X installer doesn’t allow
  repair of the damaged disk (greyed out)

The solution.  Try these options in the following order (option 2 worked for me).

Option 1: Boot from your Snow Leopard install disc and run disk utility.   Try verifying and repairing the start-up disk there.    The repair option should not be greyed out.   If it works, then restart and see if that fixes your problem (this option did not work for me after several attempts at running repair).   Since the disk cannot be verified, any attempt to create an image (.dmg) will fail with an input/output error.

Option 2: This one worked, but took a few hours. Install OS X on an external drive, transfer information from the “damaged” disk, then install OS X back on the internal drive, and transfer the information back.

1. Boot from Snow Leopard install disc (insert disc, restart and press “c”.  If that doesn’t work, restart and press “option” and select the install DVD)
2. Connect external disk and reformat it using disk utility

   - Click utilities -> disk utility
   - Select the external drive (do NOT select your internal drive, otherwise you will lose all of your data)
   - Click Partition
   - Select “1 partition”
   - Options: GUID Partition table
   - Format as “Mac OS Extended (journaled)
   - Apply
   - Quit
3. Run the OS X installer and select your newly formatted external drive as the target

   - When the install is complete, you will get an option to transfer information from another volume.
   - Select the internal volume (this is the “damaged” disk) and select all items
   - Transfer process will run for an hour or two and hopefully all of your settings, applications, users, and documents will transfer without problems
   - Complete the registration process and eject the install dvd
   - Run SW update to bring OS X to 10.6.8 (repeat SW update until all the SW is updated).   Your external drive should now be a clone of your internal drive.   Play around to see if there’s anything missing.

Now you will reverse the process to put everything back on to your internal drive

1. Boot from install DVD, start disk utility, and verify the external disk that you just created (all should be ok)
2. Perform a clean install of Snow Leopard http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3910

   - When erasing the Macintosh HD disk, format it as “Mac OS Extended (Journaled)”.  I noticed that the original format was not journaled, which may have contributed to the problem in the first place.
   - Stop at Part Three Step 4 (instead, when the migration screen appears, select transfer info from another volume)
   - Select the external volume that you just created
   - Transfer process will now move all of the information back onto your internal drive
   - Run software update to bring your internal drive back up to 10.6.8.  Keep repeating until no more software to update (2 or 3 times)
   - Ensure that everything is working ok before proceeding to next step

Optional: Configure your external drive for Time Machine backups
 - Erase the drive using disk utility
 - After the erase, the system will automatically ask you whether you want to use the external drive for Time Machine backups.   Respond to the prompts, or start Time Machine and manually configure it

Summary:  There is something wrong with the Mavericks OS X installer when trying to upgrade from OS X 10.6.8 on an “older” MacbookPro.   It seems to corrupt the internal start-up disk in such a way that disk utility can’t verify or repair it.   The data on the disk appears to be OK since a fresh install of OS X on an external drive and using the installer to transfer information from the “damaged” disk to the external drive appears to work without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has two simple articles listing the exact steps needed to fully erase your startup disk and get a clean OS installed from the Mac App Store:

- https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21973
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904

The first (PH21973) is shorter and to the point and the second has many helpful pictures, explanations and links to other resources. You should expect about 10 minutes to print out and read through the instructions, 10 minutes to do the wipe and an hour or so to download and reinstall the OS. If you have a very slow internet connection or Apple's servers are slammed due to it being the day of a major iOS or OS release, you might need 4 hours or more to complete the OS X download.

Also - some apps like iLife and iWork are *not* included in OS X even though they came with your Mac initially. Be sure you back them up or verify they show up as purchased apps if you don't want to have to buy them again. [AppleCare](https://support.apple.com) can help if you can't find your purchases or need a backup.

Answer (score 0):

If your disk is damaged beyond repair, you can try the [Target disk mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph3838) (needs a second Mac) to recover data from the disk.

Trying to [fix the disk](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1417):

Boot in Single user mode

That will allow you to enter a disk repair command

fsck -fy

good luck